# Change Access Rights to all the User at a Time in Odoo

Tags: odoo

Now i have more than 300 Users in my system. For all of them by default Human Resources : Employee is there. Now, i want to remove that Access to all of them.
I tried to access from database, but no use.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID
@api.multi    
    def update_all_users_hr_employee_access(self):    
        category_id=self.pool.get('ir.module.category').search(cr,uid,[('name','=','Human Resources')],context=context)
        group_ids=self.pool.get('res.groups').search(cr,uid,[('category_id','=',category_id[0]),('name','=','Employee')],context=context)
        group_obj = self.pool.get('res.groups').browse(cr, uid,group_ids[0],context=context)
        write_op = [(3, user.id) for user in group_obj.users if user.id!=SUPERUSER_ID]
        group_obj.write(cr, uid, [group_obj.id], {'users': write_op}, context=context)
        return True
```